# Sum list values in python

Tags: list, tuples, python-2.x

Calculate values in each column by identifier. Please see example. (Hard for me to explain :( )

Like so:

```
tdata = [
    ('column 1', [
        (1, 5), (2, 10), (3, 200)
        ]
    ), 
    ('column 2', [
        (1, 20), (2, 300), (3, 100)
        ]
    ), 
    ('column 3', [
        (1, 2), (2, 300), (3, 2000)
        ]
    )
]
```

From this data set, I need to find a pythonic way to calculate only the sub values of a tuple where the first value of the inner tuple matches.

So I would do Col1 = 5+20+2, Col2 = 10+300+300, Col3 = 200+100+2000.

I can accomplish this in a really code intensive way like so:

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
data = []
for (column_name, column_values) in tdata:
    for (key, value) in column_values:
        if key == 1:
           col1.append(value)
        elif key == 2:
           col2.append(value)
        elif key == 3:
           col3.append(value)

data = [('Column 1', sum(col1)), ('Column 2', sum(col2)), ('Column 3', sum(col3))]
```

Obviously this is a lot of code and not the most efficient way of doing this. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
rows = [x[1] for x in tdata]
col1 = sum([x[0][1] for x in rows])
col2 = sum([x[1][1] for x in rows])
col3 = sum([x[2][1] for x in rows])
```